# Python thinks I'm passing 3 arguments although I'm only passing 2

Tags: python, class, constructor

I've written a basic Vector class for dealing with vectors. Calculating their magnitude and whatnot. I have two overloaded constructors one taking two arguments `x` and `y` and one taking a tuple `(x,y)`.

When I initialize a variable it gives me the error:

> TypeError: `__init__()` takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given.

What am I missing?

```
class Vector:

    x = 0.0
    y = 0.0

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __init__(self, coordinates):
        self.x = coordinates[0]
        self.y = coordinates[1]


v1 = Vector(1,3)
print(v1.x)
```

Comment: 1) Indent your code correctly so it's in the class 2) No multiple initializers

Comment: Oh it was indented correctly in the code but I screwed up the formatting here. Deleting the 2nd constructor worked, though. Thank you, I'm a bit embarrassed now :D

Comment: Why the down votes? Its a reasonable question.

Comment: @tdelaney Probably because it's missing the complete traceback (which would have shown that it is thrown in the second `__init__`) and the "expected behaviour" is missing (why two constructors). But I don't know why exactly - I haven't downvoted.

Comment: @bananarepublic I removed the "it was easy to fix" part of the question. Instead you should either accept existing answers (if any solved your problem) or provide an answer yourself (which is also perfectly acceptable)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't support overloading, so you overwrite the first `__init__` method with the second one. The second one takes only 1 argument: `coordinates`. That Python writes 3 arguments is because the instance (`self`) is passed implicitly.

Remove the second `__init__` method and it will work correctly.

---

If you like multiple constructors you could for example implement the additional ones as `classmethods`:

```
class Vector:

    x = 0.0
    y = 0.0

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls, coordinates):
        return cls(coordinates[0], coordinates[1])
        # you could also use unpacking:
        # return cls(*coordinates)
```

Test:

```
>>> v1 = Vector(1,3)
>>> print(v1.x)
1
>>> v2 = Vector.from_list([2, 1])
>>> print(v2.x)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't do overloaded constructors - its a dynamic language and has no preknowledge of type that would allow this to happen. Your code defines an `__init__` then replaces it completely with a second `__init__`. If you want to do something like this, you could define a factory method with the alternate signature and call that.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have overloaded constructors: the second method definition overwrites the first.  Thus, your *only* surviving constructor takes only two arguments.  You supplied 3 -- *self* is implied.